# Using regex to increment part of a string within MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, regex, increment

Regexs baffle me. I have a situation where I have JSONs stored in a db. I need to go into the JSON string, find a part of it, and increment it.

In this case, the phrase I'm searching for is `"selectedLib":"x"` where x is always a number (but a number that has, in this case, been wrapped in quotes and so is technically a string).

So, `"selectedLib":"1"`, needs to become `"selectedLib":"2"`, `"selectedLib":"23"` needs to become `"selectedLib":"24"`, and so on.

This is a real head-scratcher...

Comment: MySQL can only use regexp to match strings, it doesn't have regexp replace.

Comment: I guess this should teach you not to store JSON in the database if you need to use the value. You should normalize your schema and put the data in a real table.

Comment: I know I know. The problem is that these JSONs are essentially a document format that is used by a JS front-end (Knockout). Normalizing something like that will really kill performance and add bloat.

Comment: In which case, you'll most likely need to pull the data out, increment the value, and then re-store

Comment: "add bloat", don't think you can call something bloat if it makes your database design much easier to manipulate. "kill performance", I think you are killing performance with JSON now that you will need to pull all data, increment it, and then update all data (rather than just `UPDATE table SET column+=1`).

Comment: It's a one time operation because some other db schema has changed. Something that happens extremely seldomly.

Comment: You have to use regular string functions: `LOCATE`, `SUBSTR`, `CONCAT`.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

Comment: You can store JSON in the database, but don't expect SQL to be a convenient language to manipulate it.